# Is this the way to go to render meshes?

Tags: c#, opengl

I'm learning OpenGL with the openTK librairy in c#.
I've managed to successefuly renderer triangles on my window,
and things are running properly.
However, the performance is terrible (running at half a fps with only 100k triangles).

My question is, is there anything that I am doing badly ?
how could I improve performances ?

for the most part, I've followed [this tutorial](https://learnopengl.com/Model-Loading/Mesh) translated from c++.

Here is the render method, called each frame :

```
        public static void Render()
        {
            //render the mesh render queue to the screen and clear it
            GL.UseProgram(shaderProgram.id);

            //meshRenderQueue is a List<Mesh>
            foreach(Mesh mesh in meshRenderQueue)
            {
                mesh.Draw();
            }

            meshRenderQueue.Clear();
        }
```

Here is my Mesh class :

```
    public class Mesh
    {
        private Vertex[] vertices;
        private uint[] triangles;
        private int VAO;
        private int VBO;
        private int EBO;

        public Mesh()
        {
            //create lots of unoptimized triangles to test performances
            int triCount = 100000;

            vertices = new Vertex[3 * triCount];
            for(int i = 0; i < triCount; i++)
            {
                vertices[3 * i + 0] = new Vertex(new Vector3(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0f));
                vertices[3 * i + 1] = new Vertex(new Vector3(0.5f, -0.5f, 0f));
                vertices[3 * i + 2] = new Vertex(new Vector3(0, 0.5f, 0f));
            };
            triangles = new uint[3 * triCount];
            for (int i = 0; i < triCount; i++)
            {
                triangles[3 * i + 0] = 0;
                triangles[3 * i + 1] = 1;
                triangles[3 * i + 2] = 2;
            };

            SetUpMesh();
        }


        private void SetUpMesh()
        {
            //initialize the openGL buffers
            VAO = GL.GenVertexArray();
            VBO = GL.GenBuffer();
            EBO = GL.GenBuffer();

            GL.BindVertexArray(VAO);

            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, VBO);
            GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vertices.Length * 8 * 4, vertices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);

            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, EBO);
            GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, triangles.Length * sizeof(int), triangles, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);

            //vertex positions
            GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(0);
            GL.VertexAttribPointer(0, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 8 * 4, 0);

            //vertex normals
            GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(1);
            GL.VertexAttribPointer(1, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 8 * 4, 3 * 4);

            //vertex texture coords
            GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(2);
            GL.VertexAttribPointer(2, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 8 * 4, 6 * 4);

            //unbind vertex array (what for ?)
            GL.BindVertexArray(0);
        }

        public void Draw()
        {
            //render the mesh with the given shader
            GL.BindVertexArray(VAO);
            GL.DrawElements(BeginMode.Triangles, triangles.Length, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, 0);
            GL.BindVertexArray(0);
        }


    }
```

And finally the Vertex struct, if usefull :

```
    public struct Vertex
    {
        public Vector3 position;
        public Vector3 normal;
        public Vector2 textureCoords;

        public Vertex(Vector3 pos, Vector3 norm, Vector2 textCoords)
        {
            position = pos;
            normal = norm;
            textureCoords = textCoords;
        }

        public Vertex(Vector3 pos)
        {
            position = pos;
            normal = Vector3.zero;
            textureCoords = new Vector2(0, 0);
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any help. cheers !

Comment: Happy to see a fellow OpenTK/GL learner on here :). Currently, the reason your code runs slowly is because your `Render` method essentially has the entire lifetime of your application built right into it. You only need to create the VAOs and VBOs once per mesh (most likely at program startup), same goes for filling the buffers. Then when you are to render a mesh, you bind its VAO before calling `GL.DrawArrays`.

Comment: A very basic render loop need only to consist of: **1)** Use shader program, **2)** Use texture, **3)** Bind VAO, **4)** DrawArrays/DrawElements

Comment: Please update the question with your new code. It's hard to tell what's going on without seeing what you've changed. Also, when benchmarking be sure to use the _exact_ same data as before (earlier you said 100k _triangles_, now you say 10k _meshes_. I don't know whether each mesh consists of exactly 10 triangles or not, but if you're now rendering more triangles than before then that would of course cause an impact on performance).

Comment: Nice work! The new code looks much better in terms of managing the buffer objects. Is there anything specific you are trying to achieve? Note that rendering 100k overlapping triangles will definitely hurt performance regardless of which system you're on, so it's not really an ideal benchmark test (they will be fighting for Z-space, meaning OpenGL can't really do any good form of clipping, etc.). Even with my own optimized code, only 24k overlapping triangles cause a really low FPS. If you set up a more realistic scenario I think you will see pretty decent performance numbers.